# Wordpress rewrite rule $matches[2] got me redirect

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to recreate this new url based on **model_no** without creating new pages.

```
example.com/my-book
example.com/my-book/novel/id123
example.com/my-book/novel/id444
example.com/my-book/science/id456

my-book = parent page
novel = child page
id123 = model_no
id444 = model_no

science = child page
id456 = model_no
```

My wordpress code in functions.php is:

```
function my_book_model_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%model_no%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'my_book_model_tags');

function my_book_model() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^my-book/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&model_no=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'my_book_model');
```

Currently I only able access this url to get **model_no**:
example.com/my-book/novel/?model_no=id123

But when I access example.com/my-book/novel/id123 , it redirect to example.com/my-book/novel/.

Please kindly advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks yet? Wordpress > Settings > Permalinks > Save.

Comment: @Aliqua yes I have